# switch oracle instance in hibernate dynamically

Tags: oracle, hibernate, dynamic, instance

We are using Spring , tomcat , hibernate and oracle 11.0.2. Is there a way i can switch between 2 oracle instances say(ins1 and ins2) with out restarting the application layer? Is there any setting in hibernate that allows us to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Spring's HotSwappableTargetSource that allows change beans at runtime. Maybe you can laverage it to your needs. There will still be limitations (such as same database schema in both DBs, ...)

See 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/target/HotSwappableTargetSource.html